# In-App Purchases: Stuck at paymentWithProductIdentifiers - which is deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am stuck with setting up my in-app purchases.

I can't get to get this right:

```
SKPayment *paymentRequest = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct: @"co.za.nideo.100shotsbuybeer"];
```

I got it from

```
SKPayment *paymentRequest = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifiers: @"co.za.nideo.100shotsbuybeer"];
```

but this seems to be deprecated. How can I get the first piece of code to work?

It seems to nee a SKProduct but I don't know how to create/init such an object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the StoreKit docs and [1] you'd have to:

1. Create an `SKProductsRequest` with your product identifiers (`initWithProductIdentifiers:`)
2. Set yourself as the `delegate`
3. Send this request to Apple (`start` method)
4. The Response will call your delegates `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` which contains an `SKProductsResponse` object
5. You extract the `SKProduct` objects from the `products` property and display them, saving the objects for further purchase.

This seems in line with *Important: You must make a product request for a particular product identifier before allowing the user to purchase that product. Retrieving product information from the App Store ensures that you are using a valid product identifier for a product you have marked available for sale in iTunes Connect.* from [1]

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RetrievingStoreInformation/RetrievingStoreInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW1