# SKPayment is deprecated

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Im using following for InAppPurchase payment process, `SKPayment *pay=[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:myProduct];` Is appstore reject my app or not.. I used following code for paymentWithProductIdentifier. How to use paymentWithProduct for this code

Code:

In .h file

```
#define PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER @"com.company.appname.product"
```

In .m file

```
SKRequest *request=[[SKRequest alloc]init];
    request.delegate=self;
    [request start];

SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER]];
       productRequest.delegate = self;
    [productRequest start];

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{


    SKProduct *product;
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    NSArray *myProduct1 = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;


    printf("\n inside didReceiveResponse ....myProduct count----%d\t",[myProduct count]);
    printf("\n inside didReceiveResponse ....INVALID  Products count----%d\t",[myProduct1 count]);
if([myProduct count] >0){
        for(int i=0;i<[myProduct count];i++)
        {
            product = [myProduct objectAtIndex:i];
}
        [request release];

        [self performSelector:@selector(preCheckForPayment) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];


    }   
    }

-(void)checkForPayments{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        printf("\n YES u can make payments");

SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NO,Even you used deprecated method apple don't rejects your app.

but using an [SKProduct](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RetrievingStoreInformation/RetrievingStoreInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW1) is good

visit this link for [steps of using SKProduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332735/in-app-purchases-stuck-at-paymentwithproductidentifiers-which-is-deprecated?rq=1)

Comment: Not completely true, `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` is deprecated and using it will get your app rejected. So you might want to move away from deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

No they will not reject your app, but you should be changing you `paymentWithProductIdentifier` to the [`paymentWithProduct:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008255-CH1-SW4) method.

Comment: I have my previous developer old project.  I changed only images in old project and going to live. That's y im asking. He used paymentWithProductIdentifier. Tomorrow my app going to live. I used paymentWithProductIdentifier. Surely tell me if appStore will reject or not

Comment: You should not be rejected, but results from the past are no guaranty from the future. For now I think Apple will allow it. But there is nobody but the Apple review board that can tell if you app will be rejected or not.

Comment: ok. Shall i upload my app to appStore. Im new to iOS. My client simple told me, change image only and do upload.

Comment: Yes it should, just because a method is marked deprecated does not mean it will not work. But it will be removed in a future version od iOS. You should update your code to the new methods as soon as posible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use +paymentWithProduct:.

```
+ (id)paymentWithProduct:(SKProduct *)product
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that you'll get rejected for using a deprecated API (the `uniqueIdentifier` method is a notable exception, but that's another story). On the other hand, why can't you use `paymentWithProduct:` instead?